Directly import modules in a Poetry project from a non-Poetry managed module
I have an existing codebase that I am working in, and for any new code, I am using Poetry to manage the modules, dependencies, etc. For existing code, I am slowly migrating over code, but this is obviously a bit tedious and time consuming. There is some code that still exists outside of the Poetry project, and prior to getting to the point where I can migrate it over, I would simply like to call modules within Poetry from this external file.
Here's an example of the file structure:
├───modules-project
│   │   poetry.lock
│   │   pyproject.toml
│   │
│   └───modules
│           some_client.py
│           __init__.py
│
└───scripts
        script.py

Inside script.py, I want to import some_client.py. What is the easiest way to do this? This code is all in the same repository, and given that it will eventually be rewritten or migrated into the Poetry project, I am wanting to avoid going through all the trouble of creating another Poetry project, exporting the modules Poetry project and then installing it for script.py, etc. I don't care how dirty the solution inside script.py is as long as it can see the some_client.py module and its dependencies.
# inside `script.py`

import modules-project.modules.some_client.py # <-- what should this actually be?


You have a similar question here.
There are different approaches to solve this problem.
For instance:
in script.py file write:
from ..modules-project.modules import some_client

now move outside the project's parent folder (let's suppose its called "main") and then execute python from there with the -m parameter:
python -m main.scripts.script  #without .py extension

